# Copy-Item 'preview' of output

Tags: powershell

Quick question regarding the PowerShell Copy-Item command. I was wondering if you have a directory structure and wanted to overwrite another directory structure is there a way to run the Copy-Item command in a 'preview' mode. It would output what files its overwriting from directory a to directory b but not actually perform the Copy-Item command.

Any help or advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Run `Copy-Item` with the parameter `-WhatIf`. However, for what you're trying to achieve `robocopy` would be a more suitable tool. Add the parameter `/l` for a dry-run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- **`Copy-Item -WhatIf` will not give you the level of detail you're looking for** - see below.
- **Use `robocopy.exe -l` instead** (Windows only), as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) recommends, because it individually lists what files *would* be copied, including dynamically omitting those already present in the target dir (with the same size and last-modified time stamp, by default).

  - Generally, [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is faster and more fully featured than `Copy-Item`, and it avoids [a notable pitfall of the latter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2934).

---

[`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) documents **the `-WhatIf` common parameter supported by many (but not all) cmdlets**, whose **purpose is to *preview* an operation** without actually performing it.

However, this **feature is implemented in an abstract fashion, and often doesn't provide information as detailed as one would hope.**

Case in point: while `Copy-Item` does support `-WhatIf`, it probably won't give you the level of detail you're looking for, because if the source item is a *directory*, only a *single* line such as the following is output:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: sourceDir Destination: destDir".
```

Note that you'll see the same line whether or not your `Copy-Item` call includes the `-Recurse` switch.

Even if you ensure existence of the target directory manually and append `/*` to the source directory path in order to see individual filenames, you'd only see them at the *child* level, not further down the subtree, and you'd never get the dynamic information that `robocopy -l` provides with respect to what files actually need replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!
Here is my attempt of doing it all in Powershell, so not needing RoboCopy.

```
function Copy-Preview {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByPath')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPath', Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ })]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByLiteralPath', Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ })]
        [string]$LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Destination,

        [string]$Filter = $null,
        [string]$Include = $null,
        [string]$Exclude = $null,
        [switch]$Recurse,
        [switch]$Force
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByLiteralPath') { $Path = $LiteralPath }

    # determine if $Path and $Destination hold a file or a directory
    $srcIsFolder = (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    # cannot use Test-Path here because then the path has to exist.
    # assume if it has an extension the path is a file, otherwise a directory
    # NOTE:
    # This is certainly not fullproof, so to avoid problems, always make sure 
    # the destination ends with a backslash if a directory is intended.
    $destIsFolder = (-not ([System.IO.Path]::HasExtension($Destination)))

    if ($destIsFolder -and !(Test-Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Host "Destination path does not exist yet. All files from '$Path' will be copied fresh" -ForegroundColor Green
        return
    }
    elseif ($srcIsFolder -and (!$destIsFolder)) {
        # should not happen: source is a directory, while the destination is a file..
        Write-Error "When parameter Path points to a directory, the Destination cannot be a file.."
        return
    }

    $count = 0
    if ($srcIsFolder -and $destIsFolder) {
        # Both the source and the destinations are folders
        # make sure both paths are qualified for .Replace() further down
        if (-not $Path.EndsWith("\")) { $Path += "\" }
        if (-not $Destination.EndsWith("\")) { $Destination += "\" }

        $splat = @{
            Filter  = $Filter
            Include = $Include
            Exclude = $Exclude
            Recurse = $Recurse
            Force   = $Force
        }
        # add either Path or LiteralPath to the parameters as they are mutually exclusive
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByPath') { $splat.Path = $Path }
        else { $splat.LiteralPath = $LiteralPath }

        $srcFiles  = Get-ChildItem @splat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

        # reuse the splat parameters hash for the destination, but change the Path
        if ($splat.LiteralPath) {($splat.Remove("LiteralPath"))}
        $splat.Path = $Destination

        $destFiles = Get-ChildItem @splat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

        foreach ($srcItem in $srcFiles) { 
            $destItem = $srcItem.Replace($Path, $Destination)
            if ($destFiles -contains $destItem) {
                Write-Host "'$destItem' would be overwritten"
                $count++
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (!$srcIsFolder) {
        # the source is a file
        if (!$destIsFolder) {
            # the destination is also a file
            if (Test-Path $Destination -PathType Leaf) {
                Write-Host "'$Destination' would be overwritten"
                $count++
            }
        }
        else {
            # source is file, destination is a directory
            $destItem = Join-Path $Destination (Split-Path $Path -Leaf)
            if (Test-Path $destItem -PathType Leaf) {
                Write-Host "'$destItem' would be overwritten"
                $count++
            }
        }
    }

    $msg = "$count item{0} would be overwritten by Copy-Item" -f $(if ($count -ne 1) { 's' })
    $dash = "-" * ($msg.Length)
    Write-Host "$dash`r`n$msg" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -whatif parameter.

`Copy-item -path myfile.txt -destination myfoldertoCopyTo\ -whatif`

Comment: The OP is copying a directory structure and wants to preview "what files it's overwriting", i.e., per-file information, which `-WhatIf` doesn't provide.